# Selenium: I am not able to select the option "Today Sale Update" through my code

Tags: java, selenium

I added a selenium test. In this test I am able to click on employee, but unable to click on "Today Sale update". How can i do so?

Please review my Code.

```
package Testing;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Login {

    public static void main(String\[\] args) {
        WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        String baseurl="http://203.212.70.20/vid/WebLogin.aspx ";
        driver.get(baseurl);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.id("textBoxUserName")).sendKeys("admin");
        driver.findElement(By.id("textBoxPassword")).sendKeys("1234");
        driver.findElement(By.id("explore")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("ui-accordion-accordion-header-2")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*\[@id="ui-accordion-accordion-panel-2"\]/ul/li\[6\]/a")).click();
        //Select oSelection = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ui-accordion-accordion-header-2")));
        //oSelection.selectByVisibleText("TODAY SALE UPDATE");
        driver.findelement(By.visibleText(""))
        driver.findElement(arg0)

        //oSelection.selectByIndex(1);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Comment: Check if the element has an id attribute.

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.visibleText("TODAY SALE UPDATE")).click();` doesn't work? What happens? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

As HTML shows that the option you are trying to click is a URL in List Item.

```html
<li><a href="Master/TodaySalesUpdate.aspx"> TODAY SALE UPDATE</a>
</li>
```

It worked for me with :

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("TODAY SALE UPDATE")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

The element "TODAY SALE UPDATE" is a list item not a Select option, so you will never be able to use the Select class of selenium on it. Instead you can store all the list items in a List and click an item according to your requirement. After clicking on "explore" button in the Login page you can do something like this. Try it -

```
wd.findElement(By.id("ui-accordion-accordion-header-2")).click();
    WebElement web=wd.findElement(By.id("ui-accordion-accordion-panel-2"));

    List<WebElement> list=web.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
    for(WebElement w:list){
        if(w.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("today sale update")){
            w.click();
        }
    }
```